# ISO3166 not importing method properly -Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, iso-3166

Anyone know why this is not working properly. According to https://pypi.org/project/iso3166/ this should work.

```
from iso3166 import countries
```

Get following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'countries' from 'iso3166'

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue which stemmed using an in-line pip install from my Jupyter notebook. Here a few common solutions worth trying:

- Update the package
- Uninstall and reinstall the package
- Restart your kernel (if in a notebook)

Here is what worked for me:

1. Manually deleted the library from my environment (specifically, by the file path displayed with the ImportError message)
2. Reinstalled the library using my IDE's library manager

If that still doesn't work for you, consider trying a different library, like this one: https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use countrywrangler which should also be a bit faster.

```
pip install countrywrangler
```

Here is an example code:

```
import countrywrangler as cw

alpha2 = cw.Normalize.name_to_alpha2("Germany")
print(alpha2)

>>> DE
```

There is also a fuzzy option that matches virtually any different formatting:

```
import countrywrangler as cw

alpha2 = cw.Normalize.name_to_alpha2("Germany Federal Republic of", use_fuzzy=True)
print(alpha2)

>>> DE
```

https://pypi.org/project/countrywrangler/

https://countrywrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/